# Use sum of p-values from significance tests to determine best permutation of table columns

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, combinatorics

I have a table in which there are columns which are entirely filled with numbers. Given another table, I want to figure out which permutation of the other table's columns produces an arrangement most similar to my table. More formally, I want to find the permutation of columns which maximizes the probability of each corresponding column's values coming from the same sample. I've chosen to do this by running significance tests in the following way: for each permutation, I match up the columns so that the first column in the other table is matched to the first column in my table, second to second, and so on. I then perform a significance test with the null hypothesis that the means of the two distributions are equal, and take 1 - p-value (since I want the probability of observing more evidence against the null hypothesis to be as large as possible). I then sum the p-values across the columns. The permutation with the highest p-value sum is identified to be the best permutation.

I'm not sure if summing the p-values is the best approach, and so my question is: what would be a better way to use the p-values? I can't find any articles or papers on similar situations, so I'm not sure if there is a precedent for handling something like this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This approach sounds like it is misinterpreting p-values as if they were probabilities of distributional matches.  They are not.

Comment: I understand that the p-value is the probability of observing more evidence against the null hypothesis in favour of the alternative, given that the null hypothesis is true. Assuming the null hypothesis is true (the distribution means are equal) I want there to be as little evidence to reject the null hypothesis as possible. I also know that it's not a very common way to interpret p-values (and possibly not a good way). What would be a better idea?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=combine+p-value+Fisher for one principled way to combine p-values under certain circumstances.  This begs the question of how meaningful a p-value might be as a measure of "similarity" in your application.  It's unclear what a good measure would be because you haven't explained what these columns mean or the consequences of choosing a specific permutation.

Comment: The other table, with the columns permuted according to the 'best' permutation found, will be shown to a user as a 'set expansion' of the current table's rows. This is the final step in the processing of the tables, the only thing left to do is display it to a user.

Comment: @whuber Fisher's method certainly appears to be a good idea, I hadn't come across it before. I know that the number of columns I have is around 6-8, and so I'd assume that $n$ is acceptably low to where I can compute the integral and avoid underflow